# Playing video on AVD with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm trying to place an embed video player on one of the pages of my PhoneGap application.

I am currently using the html5 video tag:

```
<video id="video1" height="240" width="360" controls="controls" onclick="this.play();">
  <source src="/android_asset/video.mp4">
</video>
```

but I can not play my video on my AVD. I tried the videojs solution too, but I could not make it work either.

Is there any way to play videos on the AVD with PhoneGap? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I've answered this before but anyway, the video tag is broken in most if not all versions of Android. Go star these issues:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22254 and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8272

In order to work around this pain in the @$$ I've written a plugin you can use on Android to play videos.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: Thank you,  I tried your plugin but everytime I call the window.plugins.videoPlayer.play() method I am getting this message on LogCat: 
03-02 13:57:50.644: I/ActivityManager(90): START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=vnd.youtube:E0UV5i5jY50} from pid 670 
and then, nothing else happens. Can you help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to move the video out of the assets directory and onto the sdcard.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell: I am not using my /android_asset folder anymore. I am using the window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0UV5i5jY50") as your samples shows.
I hanged a couple of videos (.mov, .mp4) on an IIS local site too, but now I have a message box that says: "Sorry, this video cannot be played". Any other suggestion would be very appreciated.