# Video playing on Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am working with an Android and PhoneGap application and am using the HTML5 video tag to play videos on my web page. When I play the video I get the audio output but the video is not visible. How can I play a HTML5 video on Android?

Comment: any error or warning thrown on DDMS ? you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

I've written about this issue a number of times. See my previous answer:

[Playing video on AVD with phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536104/playing-video-on-avd-with-phonegap/9536236#9536236)

Also, I'm working on monkey patching the video tag on Android so hopefully we'll have something even better soon.

Comment: HI simon, I have already gone through your given solution and able to successfully play the video , but it is getting played full screen. is there anyway that i can play this as part of the html page.

Comment: No, not right now. As I said the video tag is really broken in the web view. We are working on making the PhoneGap web view a component in 1.8 so you should soon be able to have a web view and video view in a single app but currently my full screen plugin is the only way to go.

Comment: Got it,Thanks for the information. We are waiting for the release of 1.8

Comment: Hi now we are managed to play an inlinvideo using html5 <video> tag.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asman.inlinevideodemo